# Why is it loading both ldarg.0 and ldarg.1 when there are only 1 argument?

Tags: .net-assembly, cil

I am quite confused how this assembly code works. I have tried looking around for answers but couldn't find anything. I think ldarg.0 is loaded due to an instance void, but i'm not sure why it loads ldarg.1.

Would really appreciate it if someone could explain what's going on.

```
.method public hidebysig specialname instance void set_phase(string value)
  {
    .maxstack 3
    .locals init (bool V0)
nop
ldarg.1
ldarg.0
ldfld    string KGER.Generate::_phase
call     bool [mscorlib]System.String::op_Inequality(string, string)
ldc.i4.0
ceq
stloc.0
ldloc.0
brtrue.s loc_4E8
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `ldarg.0` loads the `this` pointer, then `ldfld` replaces that with the value of `this._phase`. The code is basically doing `if (value != this._phase)`

Comment: `instance` is the key, instance methods always have one extra parameter that isn't part of the method declaration.  It is the first one, it passes the object reference.  Aka `this`.  Static methods don't have that parameter.  Compare to the syntax for extension methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is not complete, however: the portion does the following:

```
.method public hidebysig specialname instance void set_phase(string value)
  {
    .maxstack 3
    .locals init (bool V0)
```

This is the method signature. from here you infer two important things: the first is that the method is an `instance` method. This means that the first implicit argument contains `this`.
The second important thing is the signature which consists of a single argument of type string: this will be `arg1` as `arg0` is implicitly used to contain `this`.

```
nop
```

computationally, this does nothing. among other things, `nop` instructions can be used by debuggers to safely place break points

```
ldarg.1
```

this loads `arg1` onto the stack. The stack contains (**the value of the field named value**)

```
ldarg.0
ldfld    string KGER.Generate::_phase
```

then loads the `this` argument and immediately uses it to load the `KGER.Generate::_phase` field. the stack now contains (value, **the content of the _phase field**)

```
call     bool [mscorlib]System.String::op_Inequality(string, string)
```

this calls the operator `op_Inequality` of the class `String` which is a static method. the stack now contains (**result of comparison**)

```
ldc.i4.0
```

this loads 0 as integer into the stack. as we know that this value will be part of a boolean comparison, remember that 0 is equivalent to `false` for these purposes

```
ceq
```

this compares the two values into the stack and pushes the result as boolean into the stack

```
stloc.0
```

this stores the result of the comparison to a local variable (the first one)

```
ldloc.0
```

this loads the result of the comparison stored to the abovementioned local variable again into the stack, presumably this is a debug version, and this pair of instructions allows the developer to correctly view the value of the variables while debugging (or it is really needed in a part of code you didn't share)

```
brtrue.s loc_4E8
```

this jumps to the location `loc_4E8` when the value is `true` (i.e. 1), which means that if thee two strings are equal, the code will jump.